# JavaScript - Return object key and value when both are strings

Tags: javascript

So, I have this array of objects:

```
var obj = [{
    "Has the house been sold?": "N"
}, {
    "Is the house on the market?": "Y"
}, {
    "Duration of Sale": "2 weeks"
}];
```

and I am trying to turn it so that it key and value are like this:

```
var obj = [
    {key: 'Has the house been sold?', value: 'N'}
];
```

But I cannot find a way to grab the key text because it only gives me the `index`.

```
for (var key in obj) {
    if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, key)) {
        var val = obj[key];
        console.log(val);
    }
}
```

Can someone help me out here? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) for own properties.

```js
var obj = [{ "Has the house been sold?": "N" }, { "Is the house on the Market?": "Y" }, { "Duration of Sale": "2 weeks" }],
array = obj.map(function (a) {
    var key = Object.keys(a)[0];
    return { key: key, value: a[key] };
});
console.log(array);
```

ES6

```js
var obj = [{ "Has the house been sold?": "N" }, { "Is the house on the Market?": "Y" }, { "Duration of Sale": "2 weeks" }],
array = obj.map(a => (key => ({ key:key, value: a[key] }))(Object.keys(a)[0]));
console.log(array);
```

Comment: Beat you to it by 30 seconds ;P

Comment: I beat all y'all, though I didn't use `map`. That would have been a good idea

Comment: Argh. That's right. Access the first one of each loop using ... argh. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use `Array.map()`.

```
var obj = [{
    "Has the house been sold?": "N"
}, {
    "Is the house on the market?": "Y"
}, {
    "Duration of Sale": "2 weeks"
}];

var newObj = obj.map(function(ea, i){
    var thisKey = Object.keys(ea)[0];
    return {key: thisKey, value: ea[thisKey]};
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through each item in `obj` since it is an array, and then for each item, loop through its properties and then save them.

```
var obj = [{
    "Has the house been sold?": "N"
}, {
    "Is the house on the market?": "Y"
}, {
    "Duration of Sale": "2 weeks"
}];

var newObj = [];

for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
  for (var key in obj[i])
  {
    newObj.push({key: key, value: obj[i][key]})
  }
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(newObj))
```

Answer (score 1):

Or just with a forEach

```
var arr = [];
obj.forEach(item => {arr.push({key : Object.keys(item)[0], value : item[Object.keys(item)][0]})})
console.log(arr);
```